# Find a string after a certain character

Tags: regex

An example will explain it better:

```
structure_1/structure_2/<I NEED WHAT'S HERE/structure_3
```

- Structure_1 is always the same value
- Structure_2 is a string that can be of any size, sometimes with _ or -
- What I need is behind the second forward slash
- I don't care what comes after

Other example:

```
order/shirt/blue_stripes/America
order/pants_ripped/green/Europe
order/skirts/yellow-folded/Asia
order/socks/orange/Africa
```

Results that I want to become after regex

```
blue_stripes
pants_ripped
yellow-folded
orange
```

I'm writing a BASH script for my Unix machine

**UPDATE**
I first used a regex in order to do this but I was informed by *Flying* that it would be better to use the command *'awk'* and this did the trick with ease!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one will do the trick: `^(?:[^\/]+\/){2}([^\/]+)`. You're basically need to skip first 2 groups of chars. You can check it by yourself [here](https://regex101.com/r/h7LLQ6/2).

**UPDATE:** Since, as defined into comment, actual task is not about finding correct regular expression, but about grepping information from Unix file - it is much better to use `awk` instead:

```
awk -F"/" '{print $3}' orders.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the regex but regretfully it doesn't work. I used this regex with my 'grep'-command and I basically get the whole text file back (the lines I want to check are stored within 1 txt file so probably there are some newlines I need to filter out

Comment: @Dragonix sorry, but in this case your question is irrelevant. Regular expression is used for matching strings, if you want to extract information - you need to use additional code around it. In your particular case - there is no need to use regexp at all because there is much better alternative to use `awk` instead. It is specifically written to deal with such tasks. I'll update answer now.

Comment: Wauw! It could be that easy!!! Thanks man! (PS: I didn't put you on -1 ;) just for the record!)